# Is there a way to pin answers from Stack Overflow, to a collection of my own account?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I want to remember answers that helped me (but I can't always), so I want to pin them and collect in an online folder (like in Pinterest).

If there isn't such a thing, here is an idea for you guys/gals :)

Comment: Please read the tag `stack-overflow` for more information about your question.

Comment: You can click on the little star under the voting buttons next to each question to add them to your "favourites", which you can then view in your profile [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3296509/user3296509?tab=favorites). There you will also get a bit of information if something changes in one of your favourites, like new answers or edits. Is that what you want?

Comment: There are a cornucopia of products out there that do this job, not the least of which is Pinterest, also [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/), [Start.me](https://start.me/), etc.